# telegram custom KeyboardButton doesn't work. After execution, no buttons apper in telegram, no erros occur

Tags: python-3.x, keyboard, telegram-bot

python version 3.8.3

```
import telegram #imorted methodts
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
import requests
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton 
from telegram.ext.messagehandler import MessageHandler
import json

# below is function defined the buttons to be return
def start(bot, update):
 button1 = KeyboardButton("hello")
 button2 = KeyboardButton("by")
 keyboard = [button1, button2] 
 reply_markup = telegram.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
 chat_id = update.message.chat_id
 bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text='please choose USD or EUR', reply_markup = reply_markup) # it works and returns text if reply_markup parameter disabled.

def main(): 
 updater = Updater('my token')
 dp = updater.dispatcher
 dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
 updater.start_polling()
 updater.idle()

main()
```

buttons are not working. Please help to check what could be the reason of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try using string instead of keyboard button:

```
def start(bot, update):
 keyboard = [["USD", "EUR"]]
 reply_markup = telegram.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
 chat_id = update.message.chat_id
 bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text='please choose USD or EUR', reply_markup = reply_markup)

def main(): 
 updater = Updater('my token')
 dp = updater.dispatcher
 dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
 updater.start_polling()
 updater.idle()

main()
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for feedback. Indeed, progress is here, but for some reason, telegram shows buttons like: USD: U , S , D and E, U, R. All symbols in separate button.

Answer (score 0):

Add [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig), so you'll be able to see if there are any errors or response with error there.

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for feedback, however I have launched my telegram bot with this function, but no errors were found. IN assume my the issue occurs because of telegram library I use. bot succefully returns bot.send_message showing no errors in logs.